# Android Studio - Google API STATUS_SNAPSHOT_NOT_FOUND does not trigger

Tags: android

```js
AsyncTask < Void, Void, Integer > task = new AsyncTask < Void, Void, Integer > () {@
  Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(Void...params) {
    Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result;
    result = Games.Snapshots.open(mGoogleApiClient, currentSaveName, true, Snapshots.RESOLUTION_POLICY_LAST_KNOWN_GOOD).await();

    int status = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
    Snapshot snapshot = null;

    if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
      snapshot = result.getSnapshot();
      Log.i(TAG, "SUCCESS LAODED");
    }

    if (snapshot != null) {
      try {
        readSavedGame(snapshot);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error while reading snapshot contents: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
    return status;
  }

  @
  Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Integer status) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Snapshot loaded: " + status);

    if (status == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_SNAPSHOT_NOT_FOUND) {
      Log.i(TAG, "Error: Snapshot not found");
    }

    if (mLoadingDialog != null && mLoadingDialog.isShowing()) {
      mLoadingDialog.dismiss();
      mLoadingDialog = null;
    }
    hideAlertBar();
    updateUi();
  }
};

task.execute();
```

When user starts the app for first time, when there is no previous data saved in google drive, the onPostExecute does not trigger at STATUS_SNAPSHOT_NOT_FOUND. How can I get notified when user starts the app for first time? And how can I know if there is no previous data so that I can over-write a new empty save game safely into google drive?